# Coloring an asp:button - cant seem to get it to work

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, button, user-interface

```
<asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="Send" Width="80px" CssClass="ButtonClass" style="color:Red;"/>
```

I've tried adding a class and the style tag does not seem to effect anything. Am I doing something wrong?

Also tried:

```
$("input[id$=btnOK]").button();
$('input[id$=btnOK]').removeClass('defaultClass ui-state-default').addClass('ButtonClass');
```

Comment: @VisioN. Not with Asp.Net ... this crap has a client-id thing. `:)`

Comment: @gdoron that depends on which version of .Net. If using 4.0 and you aren't ina  repeating element you can set the `clientidmode='static'`  http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using asp.net 4.0 you can set the `ClientIdMode="Static"` on the button and then reference it as:

`$('#btnOK')`

More Info on the ClientIDMode.  http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx

Otherwise you can reference it this way:

`$('#<%=btnOK.ClientID%>')`

Comment: His selector `$=` select the button, It's probably a reference to jQuery ui thing.

Comment: @VisioN. a Programmer is a male until proven otherwise. `:)`

Comment: If it is a specific style that isn't applying then you'd need to build a jsfiddle or post a link to see what css rules are taking precedence.  Typically if you use firebug you can change them on the fly to see what happens and then modify your code.

Comment: @gdoron Very funny and almost always true! +1